# Is there a C compiler flag to check function modified input parameter?

Tags: c, constants, compiler-flags

I was wondering, is there a flag for the C compiler ( i.e. GCC or GHS) to check whether an input parameters is modified or not?

I mean, if I have the following function, `x` and `y` may be modified within the function ( as it happening now) if I don't add the `const` to them. So I was wondering whether the compiler can detect that situation or not and  whether there exists a flag to do so.

```
int16_t myFunc(int16_t* x ,int16_t* y, bool* e) 
{   
     int16_t z = 0;

     z = *x + *y;
     *x = 16; // this is wrong on purpose and I would like to detect it
      
     if ( z < 0)
     {
         *e = true;
     }

    return z;
}
```

Comment: no, the point of leaving out `const` is to allow the function to modify that variable. Is there a reason why you can't use `const` here?

Comment: Do you mean at debug time? Do you want to detect when a variable gets modified?

Comment: @phuclv no there is no specific reason, but rather not to have all input parameters prefixed with `const`

Comment: @DavidRanieri I would like to detect it at compilation time

Comment: @0___________ he has changed the code way before you've posted your answer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky because answers take time to be written. (Maybe you do it in 1us - I do not)

Comment: @0___________ indeed, I did change it before even you replied, if I wouldn't care about other people efforts to help me, I would have not even modified the post to be more clear...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing you want to do here is use `const` like this:

```
int16_t myFunc(const int16_t* x ,int16_t* y, bool* e)
{
   ...
   *x = 42;  // compiler error here
   ...
}
```

Here the compiler will issue a diagnostic such as `assignment of read-only location '*x'`.

That's what the `const` keyword is used for, that's the "flag" you're looking for.

You should put `const` on pointer parameters whenever possible. If you know that the object pointed by a parameter won't be modified, use `const`.

Comment: But without  `const int16_t* ` there is no other way to check that `*x` is modified, the usage of `const` is more the convention rather than the check?

Comment: @ndarkness yes there is, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: ok, I saw your edited line regarding to compiler issue just now. Thanks!

Comment: @ndarkness the `// compiler error here` comment was there from the beginning

Comment: @Jabberwocky rather `const int16_t * const x`

Comment: @0___________ the OP was mentioning `*x = 16` not `x = whatever` or `x++`.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering, is there a flag for the C compiler to check whether an input parameters is modified or not?

There are many C compilers. I heard of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), [TinyCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyCC), [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/).... (on Linux; most of them are open source and you can download their source code and improve it). And you could write your own one.

A function `myFunc` could pass the address of some `int16_t tab[12];` to another called function `myOtherFunc` which calls conditionally a third function `myBizarreFunc` which would modify `tab[3]`

And many C code have [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer). That function pointer could be computed -in practice- at runtime (e.g. on Linux with [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html), or using [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/)...) and later used in some indirect call.

If you use a recent GCC (in 2021, [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) at least), you could write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to do the static analysis you want (on [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) representations, perhaps also using the [Ghudi library](https://project.inria.fr/gudhi/)). You could base your development on the [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) static source code analyzer. See also (in 2021) [this](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-doc.pdf) DRAFT report.

If you use GCC, you can compile *and link* with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -flto -O2` and more [static analyzer flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html) like `-fanalyzer` at least.

Look also into projects like [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) or [CompCert](https://compcert.org/), static analysis tools like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [AbsInt](https://www.absint.com/)

Be aware of theoretical limitations related to [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems), [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), [No free lunch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem), the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

### I believe that the check you want to do is not always possible reliably at compile time.

You could be interested by [abstract interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation) techniques.

You could be interested by instrumenting tools (modifying the generated machine code) like the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) or [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/), and in some cases you could write your own one (perhaps as a C to C code transformer).

See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273698/why-are-there-so-few-c-compilers/273711#273711) and [that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) answers

Comment: I was aiming for GCC or GHS compiler

Comment: +1 Basil. Very nice answer. But I think it is far beyond OPs knowledge at the moment. Even building the gcc for beginners is a very difficult task.